# Is there an Alternative to using ActiveInspector and ActiveExplorer when getting a selected Email's ID?

Tags: c#, .net

im working on a small outlook project and i just wanted to know, If i wanted to get the details of a selected email in the inbox such as the EmailID is there other ways to get those details besides ActiveExplorer and ActiveInspector. I am using this method to get the details i want right now:

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem   = null;
Outlook.Inspector inspector = Application.ActiveInspector();

mailItem       = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
string EntryID = mailItem.EntryID;
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: Nothings wrong with it, just wanted to see if this was the only and best way of getting those details

Comment: If you don't actually have a problem getting your code functioning, please consider posting your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  It's been a few years since I was in the Outlook object model, unfortunately, so I can't think of a better way to do what you're asking.

Comment: @rory.ap At the moment this question really is not suited to the Code Review Community. This question would be closed because it isn't even a full function and for C# we prefer a whole class including the using statements.